# AngularJS sending values between screens

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui, monaca

I am building a cross platform app using Onsen UI, Monaca and AngularJS.

I have 2 screens. The first is where a user have to enter a Vehicle ID which calls an API. Based on the input Vehicle ID, I want to populate the API URL with this value and on the next screen display a list of all options that are returned as a JSON object based on the Vehicle ID.

E.g the API call looks as follows: *mymadeupdomain/api/vehicle.php?id=**109***

Where ***109*** would be the ID the user enters to determine what will be displayed on the detailed vehicle screen.

I have hard-coded the values and I can read back the JSON object that is returned, but I cant seem to send the values for when the user enters them.

**vehicle-id.html** form that gets the vehicle id from the user

```
<form class="login-form" style="text-align: center" name="myForm">
    <section style="padding: 8px">
        <input type="text" 
        class="text-input--underbar" 
        required 
        minlength="3" 
        maxlength="10" 
        ng-model-options="{ debounce : 800 }"
        placeholder="Vehicle ID / Fleet Number" 
        ng-model="fleetIDSearch" >
    </section>
</form>
```

**app.js** is the controller for handling the form check

```
angular.module("myApp", ['onsen']).controller("vehicleController", function($scope, $http)
{
    // Watch for changes on the vehicle ID screen
    $scope.$watch('fleetIDSearch', function()
    {
       fetchFleetDetails(); 
    });

    $scope.fleetIDSearch = "";

    function fetchFleetDetails()
    {
        $http.get("http://mymadeupdomain/api/vehicle.php?id=" + $scope.fleetIDSearch).success(function(data)
        {
            $scope.fleetIDs = data;
        });
    }

    // Returns a list of all Vehivle Checks associated with Vehicle ID
    $http.get("http://mymadeupdomain/api/getfleetchecks.php?fleetid=" + $scope.fleetIDSearch).success(function(data) // NOT WORKING HERE
    {
        $scope.checkItemDescriptions = data;
    });
});
```

How do I get values entered in $scope.fleetIDSearch = ""; in the first screen and pass them to the API URL in the second screen?

I want to display a list of all checks associated with the ID as per below - working when API URL is hard coded

**vehicleCheck.html**

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="list__item" ng-repeat="checkItemDescription in checkItemDescriptions">
        {{checkItemDescription.checkitemdesc}}
        <label class="switch switch--list-item">
            <input type="checkbox" 
                class="switch__input" 
                checked >
            <div class="switch__toggle"></div>
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple choice in your case, at multiple levels.

If you want to simply share data between controllers, you can use [Factories](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers)

Another solution is to:

- Manage a ng-model on your first page
- When the form is submitted, redirect to an url looking like /content/:id
- Manage your request (fetching remote data) inside of the router resolver
- Take the result directly in the other controller of the other page